# git - can't push to remote, error 'fatal: Not a git repository'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, git, github, git-push

I am having problems setting up Git with Github. I am following the instruction on the Rails tutorial online on their site, but I am getting a fatal error. Now I want to remove the connection to see if that solves the problem, but its not letting me, keeps giving me a fatal error. I did this:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:<myusername>/first_app.git
$ git push origin master
```

The error is:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

first_app is already created on github, so i am confused. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to have a local git repository for first_app:

1. cd to `/the/dir/with/first_app`
2. Create the git repository with: `git init`

   - This will create a 'hidden' `.git/` directory which (basically) holds all the source controlled files that are checked in.

Then `git remote add` to add the remote you want, then you can push the code to it (or pull from it).

You can now think of the 'regular' visible files (the ones that existed in the directory before adding git) as working 'copies'.  The (full) file copies that are actually under `.git/` are the ones being managed by source control, i.e. that is 'where' you are committing files 'to'.  So when you add and commit a file it is the `.git/` directory that is getting the file. and when you then 'push' it, it goes to the remote.

Comment: Yea, I figured out that was my error. Thanks for elaborating!

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialize a git repository in your local app?
The command is as follows.

```
git init
```

Then you can add an origin, copying it from GitHub.

Comment: Yea I did. And I realized what my problem was! At least after searching. What wasn't explained was that you have to be in the root directory where init was initialized. I also mistakenly misspelled my username (case difference). But I found out where it was located, which is in the config file in the .git.